# CE mark for art works. Necessary?

Tags: safety, ce

Im making lamps which are hand built, and each one is sold as a signed one out of a series of a predetermined number.

The lamps are made of plexiglas, they use an LED strip which is connected to a cable I make with a switch on it - that ends with a female connector like this one:[image: barrel connector]

With the lamps I sell standard power supply that I buy in Europe (comes with a CE mark). The power supply has an output of 12 Volts.

I read lots of documents and still cannot figure out if I need a CE mark to sell in europe. the product is below 50V and it is art and does not fall in any of the categories of the CE mark.

Anybody had to deal with such a thing?

Thank you all in advance
Eitan

Comment: You need a CE mark to sell any electronic product in the EU, regardless of whether or not it is "art" (there are a few exceptions such as development kits for research applications). Things get simpler though if everything is built from components which are individually CE marked.

Comment: Thank you Tom. Yes all the components I use are CE marked. that's why I buy them in Germany and not directly from China

Comment: It may also depend on how you are marketing them. If they are being sold as lamps they definitely would require CE certification. If they are sold as a limited series of art then it is not so clear. As a conglomeration of CE approved parts, one could argue certification of the assembly is not necessary. Ultimately, you need to ask the right authority here, advice given from lay-people on-line will not protect you.

Answer (score 6):

An item composed entirely of CE-marked parts might be easier to certify, but does not automatically make it comply.  For example, if you combine two electronic products, each which comply with CE, but when working together their interactions either create a hazardous situation, or emit EMI in excess of permissible limits, you would not have a CE-compliant device on your hands.

You're on the right track with doing a lot of reading, because you must read the scope of the [CE directives which may be relevant](https://cemarking.net/eu-ce-marking-directives/) and determine if they apply to you.  Then you work to comply with their requirements.

Assuming you never see more than 50V in your lamp, you may need to still at least comply with the [General Product Safety Directive](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2002:011:0004:0017:en:PDF).  If it contains electronics which may generate electromagnetic emissions, you will also have to comply with the [EMC directive](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=OJ:JOL_2014_096_R_0079_01&qid=1396511671603&from=EN) as well.  The [RoHS directive](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32011L0065&from=EN) also likely applies, since the EU likes to be assured your electronics do not contain lead and other hazardous chemicals.